# How to sort websites into categories based on keyword content

Tags: keyword, ontology, wordnet, categorization

I'm writing a webrobot which categorizes sites based on there keyword/meta/links into a predefined list of categories.

I've been looking at various ontology approaches and have looked at Wordnet (for the hypernym/hyponym), ResearchCyc , WebKb and was wondering if this was as hard a problem as I'm thinking or has it been solved somewhere else before.

Essentially I have large stacks of sorted keyword values and would like to use them to match against a category name. My current thoughts are to check against the category name in some kind of ontology hierarchy.

Has anyone else approached a ontology based problem like this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at text mining, specifically keyword mining or [subject indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_indexing), research.